# Quais são as etapas do ciclo de vida de uma activity e fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-activity

Quais são as etapas do ciclo de vida de uma activity e fragment? Quais são as diferenças dessas etapas? E como posso identificar em qual etapa uma activity ou fragment de uma aplicação se encontra no momento?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No próprio [site de desenvolvimento do Google](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) tem essas informações, apesar de estar em inglês tem um diagrama bem fácil de entender.

> ## [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)
>
> [image]

E em relação a como identificar em qual etapa uma Activity se encontra você deverá implementar um código que sobrescreve cada método do ciclo de vida da Activity para atualizar o status:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MinhaActivity extends Activity {
private CicloDeVida cicloDeVida;

public enum CicloDeVida
{
    onCreate,
    onStart,
    onResume,
    onRestart,
    onPause,
    onStop,
    onDestroy
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    cicloDeVida = CicloDeVida.onCreate;
}

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    cicloDeVida = CicloDeVida.onStart;
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    cicloDeVida = CicloDeVida.onResume;
}

@Override
protected void onRestart()
{
    super.onRestart();

    cicloDeVida = CicloDeVida.onRestart;
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();

    cicloDeVida = CicloDeVida.onPause;
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();

    cicloDeVida = CicloDeVida.onStop;
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();

    cicloDeVida = CicloDeVida.onDestroy;
}
```

}

Comment: eu queria uma explicacao sua... e nao um copia e cola.. e ainda esta em ingles... e nao apresentou minha outra pergunta "E como posso identificar em qual etapa uma activity ou fragment de uma aplicação se encontra no momento?"

Comment: Editei, veja se responde a sua pergunta

Answer (score 6):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Funcionamento de cada método de uma Activity:**

**onCreate()** - É a primeira função a ser executada em uma Activity. Geralmente é a responsável por carregar os layouts XML e outras operações de inicialização. É executada apenas uma vez.

**onStart()** - É chamada imediatamente após a onCreate() – e também quando uma Activity que estava em background volta a ter foco.

**onResume()** - Assim como a onStart(), é chamada na inicialização da Activity e também quando uma Activity volta a ter foco. Qual a diferença entre as duas? A onStart() só é chamada quando a Activity não estava mais visível e volta a ter o foco, a onResume() é chamada nas “retomadas de foco”.

**onPause()** - É a primeira função a ser invocada quando a Activity perde o foco (isso ocorre quando uma nova Activity é iniciada)                      .

**onStop()** - Só é chamada quando a Activity fica completamente encoberta por outra Activity.

**onDestroy()** - A última função a ser executada. Depois dela, a Activity é considerada “morta” – ou seja, nao pode mais ser relançada. Se o usuário voltar a requisitar essa Activity, um novo objeto será contruído.

**onRestart()** - Chamada imediatamente antes da onStart(), quando uma Activity volta a ter o foco depois de estar em background.

---

Agora vamos imaginar que o usuário estava navegando na sua aplicação e de repente clicou no botão HOME o que acontece na sua app:

- O Android chamará os métodos: **onPause() e onStop().**
- Caso o usuário volte para sua app então o o**nRestart(), onStart() e onResume()** e sua app voltará a funcionar dai.

Agora vamos imaginar que o usuário está dentro da sua aplicação e clica em um botão chamando outra Activity. Ele navega na Activity nova e de repente ele clica no botão Voltar o que acontece com nossas Activities ?

- O Android irá chamar o método **onPause()** da segunda Activity pausando assim qualquer interação.
- Será chamado os métodos: **onRestart(), onStart() e onResume()** da Activity anterior.
- Se tudo ocorrer bem então o android chama os métodos **onStop() e onDestroy()** da segunda activity matando assim a segunda tela e mostrando a primeira tela linda e pronta para funcionar.

---

Para identificar as etapas, voce pode fazer da seguinte forma: Botão Direito>Generate>Override Methods(Sobrescrever metodos), e adicionar os metodos onCreate, onStart, onStop, onDestroy, on Restart... Será adicionado na Activity.java o seguintes comandos para cada metodo selecionado:

```
    protected void onStart() 
   {
     super.onStart();
   }
    protected void onRestart() 
   {
    super.onRestart();
   }
```

...e assim para todos os métodos. Para identificar a etapa que se encontra, você pode adicionar uma mensagem na tela em cada metodo, com a descrição da etapa, por exemplo, no meotodo onStart adicionar: `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"onStart Metodo Chamado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` 
Ficando da seguinte forma:

```
protected void onStart() 
{
    super.onStart();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"onStart Metodo Chamado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

http://www.devmedia.com.br/entendendo-o-ciclo-de-vida-de-uma-aplicacao-android/22922