# Fragments funcionam como um activity?

Tags: java, android

Eu vi que para continuar usando um Navigation Drawer, eu tenho que usar Fragments, ou eu posso usar activity ? ou não existe alguma diferença entre os dois ?

Comment: Relacionada (ou duplicada):[Qual a diferença entre Activity, FragmentActivity e Fragment?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128133/qual-a-diferença-entre-activity-fragmentactivity-e-fragment)

Comment: Relacionada:[Quais são as etapas do ciclo de vida de uma activity e fragment?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34607/28595)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ideia dos `Fragment` é representar comportamento ou uma interface de usuário dentro de uma `Activity`. Em uma `Activity` você pode ter vários `Fragment`. E você pode até utilizar `Fragment` em outras `Activity`. Com isso, é possível escrever aplicações Android mais componentizadas e reutilizáveis.